# Composite Key with subclass in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have a Class system

```
@Entity
abstract class System{
@Id
int systemId;
//setter and getters..
}
```

and which is extended by class

```
@Entity
class PhysicalSystem extends System
{
@Id
int place;
//setter and getters..
}
```

in need to make the composite key by using the systemId and place
how can i do this.. if i have @Id in both class its throws exception

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.JoinedSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
```

How can i solve this?

Tables:

```
System{
systemid PK
systemName
}

PhysicalSystem
{
systemId PK
locationId PK
}
```

Comment: Could you post your involved tables?

Comment: Edited the Question with tables

Answer (score 0):

In your case, maybe the best solution is a OneToOne mapping:

```
@Entity
public class PhysicalSystem implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PhysicalSystemKey key;  

    @JoinColumns({JoinColumn(name = "key.systemId", referencedColumnName = "ctvId"})
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "physicalSystem")
    private System system;

    // ...
}

@Embeddable
public class PhysicalSystemKey {

    private Long systemId;

    private Long locationId;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class System implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long systemId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "system")
    private PhysicalSystem physicalSystem;
}
```

Comment: But i need to extend the System in PhysicalSystem because System is abstract class